# Making sure interview requests aren't thrown away

Tags: job-search

I have another informational interview question. I'm sending out some "cold" letters seeking informational interviews to folks with whom I don't have prior connections. I want to make sure that the letters make it to the recipient and aren't disposed of in the mailroom. How can I ensure that the letters actually get to the right person?

One thing I'm considering is labeling the envelopes "personal" or "confidential". Is there any value or harm in this? My instinct is that marking the envelopes as such might make the recipient uncomfortable. E.g., I don't want colleagues to think I'm doing personal stuff on company time.

Comment: Why do you want to send a physical letter? Seems like it would be better to email or call someone.

Answer (score 3):

Your instinct is correct.  If I got something like that at work, I'd first be nervous, then be outraged.

Anything labeled "personal" or "confidential" would immediately get the tongues wagging from anyone who saw it in the mailroom, right up to anyone seeing it on my desk.

I would **immediately** blackball you from the company because you've embarrassed me.  If you're doing cold calls, a letter is fine, but it's far better to network because at least the person would know it's coming.

Everyone knows someone.  You are no more than six connections away from the entire world.  Use your friends to connect you, if you can.  If you must cold call, do NOT label the letter.

Comment: I concur. I continue to get mail from credit card companies where the envelope simply says "Personal and Confidential" and I get furious as soon as I open it and it is spam. I imagine a similar reaction would occur for a hiring manager.

Comment: An interesting project for you Richard - Please find those six personal connections between me and you.

Comment: @EdHeal I'm in the UK in one connection from several people I know personally through the multinational corporations I've worked for.  If you've ever worked in the financial or medical sectors, I'm probably closer than you might realize

Comment: TOSHIBA perhaps?

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'm using a letter because I lack a pre-existing connection & haven't run into my targets at networking events.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to make sure that the letters make it to the recipient and
>   aren't disposed of in the mailroom. How can I ensure that the letters
>   actually get to the right person?

You are worried about nothing.

I know of no company where someone in the mailroom would take it upon themselves to throw out someone else's mail.

Simply make sure you have the correct person's name and address on your mail and it will almost certainly get to that person. No need for special labels like "Personal" or "Confidential".

Comment: There is an exception if the recipient is a senior executive with a personal assistant who filters non-personal mail. In that case, the executive would be very annoyed by a fake "personal" letter, and the blackballing would be particularly effective. The PA would know how to handle an interview request - which might involve passing the letter to someone who is hiring.